# Magento: get max and min price for bundle product

Tags: magento, bundle, max, product, min

I tried several ideas I could find at google, but no one did work for me for few days. Finally I found a way to display in a custom extension the "minimal possible price" and the "maximal possible price" for a bundle product in magento:

```
    $_product_id            = YOUR_BUNDLE_PRODUCT_ID;

    // highest possible price for this bundle product
    $return_type            = 'max'; // because I used this in a helper method

    // lowest possible price for this bundle product
    // $return_type         = 'min';

    $model_catalog_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); // getting product model
    $_product               = $model_catalog_product->load( $_product_id );

    $TypeInstance           = $_product->getTypeInstance(true);
    $Selections             = $TypeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($OptionIds, $_product );
    $Options                = $TypeInstance->getOptionsByIds($OptionIds, $_product);
    $bundleOptions          = $Options->appendSelections($Selections, true);

    $minmax_pricevalue      = 0; // to sum them up from 0

    foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
        if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {

            $bundleSelections       = $bundleOption->getSelections();

            $pricevalues_array  = array();
            foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {

                $pricevalues_array[] = $bundleSelection->getPrice();

            }
                if ( $return_type == 'max' ) {
                rsort($pricevalues_array); // high to low
                } else {
                sort($pricevalues_array);   // low to high
                }

            // sum up the highest possible or lowest possible price
            $minmax_pricevalue += $pricevalues_array[0];


        }
    }

    // echo $minmax_pricevalue;
    echo ''.Mage::helper('core')->currency($minmax_pricevalue, true, false).'';
```

If you have better and shorter ways feel free to post here. Thanks to all involved!

**Background** of all was that, I have made a custom extension and wanted also to show there the "minimal possible price" and the "maximal possible price" for such a configuration. Magento-Setup was: Native "bundle product" several "Bundle Items Options" connected my "bundle product". Each "bundle option" has multiple simple products with different prices in it. I think that was the point here.

Hope that all helps someone - love to share such stuff :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here once again the final working code:

```
$_product_id            = YOUR_BUNDLE_PRODUCT_ID;

// highest possible price for this bundle product
$return_type            = 'max'; // because I used this in a helper method

// lowest possible price for this bundle product
// $return_type         = 'min';

$model_catalog_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); // getting product model
$_product               = $model_catalog_product->load( $_product_id );

$TypeInstance           = $_product->getTypeInstance(true);
$Selections             = $TypeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($OptionIds, $_product );
$Options                = $TypeInstance->getOptionsByIds($OptionIds, $_product);
$bundleOptions          = $Options->appendSelections($Selections, true);

$minmax_pricevalue  = 0; // to sum them up from 0

foreach ($bundleOptions as $bundleOption) {
    if ($bundleOption->getSelections()) {


        $bundleSelections       = $bundleOption->getSelections();

        $pricevalues_array  = array();
        foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {

            $pricevalues_array[] = $bundleSelection->getPrice();

        }
            if ( $return_type == 'max' ) {
            rsort($pricevalues_array); // high to low
            } else {
            sort($pricevalues_array);   // low to high
            }

        // sum up the highest possible or lowest possible price
        $minmax_pricevalue += $pricevalues_array[0];


    }
}

// echo $minmax_pricevalue;
echo ''.Mage::helper('core')->currency($minmax_pricevalue, true, false).'';
```

Comment: For the missing $OptionIds causing the error you can add $OptionIds              = $TypeInstance->getOptionsIds($_product);

Answer (score 9):

Magento has build in function for that purpose:

```
Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'min',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and came up with this (with some help from [Inchoo's blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-get-bundled-items-by-bundle-product/) for getting the bundled product collection).  It loads all of the bundled products associated with the main `product_id` into an array.  By sorting the array you get the min on the bottom and max at the end which I retrieved with `$bundled_prices[0]` and `array_slice($bundled_prices, -1, 1, false)`.

```
    $product_id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;

    $bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $bundled_product->load($product_id);
    $selectionCollection = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
    );
    $bundled_items = array();
    foreach($selectionCollection as $option) { 
        if ($option->getPrice()!="0.0000"){                 
            $bundled_prices[]=$option->getPrice();
        }
    }

    sort($bundled_prices);

    $min_price=$bundled_prices[0];
    $max_price_tmp=array_slice($bundled_prices, -1, 1, false);
    $max_price=$max_price_tmp[0];

    echo "Min: " . $min_price . '<br>'; 
    echo "Max: " . $max_price;
```

Comment: If I try this code I get wrong values for both. Min: 0.0000 and Max: 2604.6200. Comparing to default bundle-output of magento-code I get Min: 2.052,45 € and Max: 4.346,62 €. Any further ideas?

Comment: Hey @seanbreeden, I changed my codes like you suggested - but still wrong values - I think it´s something wrong with the whole calculation of the price. Strage that nobody has a similar question.

Comment: This works for me with bundled products.  What were the values with the modified code?

Comment: The values were indeed min and max from all connected bundle items, but like I said from all of them. I have a solution now, going to add it to my post above.

Comment: This code does not take into account disabled products in the bundle.  Need to add a check for `$option->getStatus( ) == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED` in the `foreach`